# HttpPostAttribute not found?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I just opened up a project I have done in MVC a while back, fired right up I looked at in the browser and now all of the sudden it just won't find the `[HttpPost]` & `[HttpPostAttribute]`. What can be the problem?

error message

> The type or namespace name 'HttpPost' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**EDIT:**

If I comment out the `[HttpPost]` I get that global is missing the UrlParameter and AreaRegistration?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Security;
using PROJECT.Web.Models;
```

Comment: Post your `using` declarations?

Comment: The same thing has happened to me WHILE using the project. It compiled and ran, I typed a comment in the controller and this message appeared. No changes to references, no updating of MVC version. If I take out the [HttpPost] everything works perfectly, very strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a new ASP.NET MVC project. If this project fails you have deinstalled some needed parts, if it works your existing project is screwed up.

Answer (score 13):

You're probably referencing the System.Web.Mvc version 1.0.0.0 dll instead of 2.0.0.0.  Check the reference to that, and if it's wrong, remove it and re-add the correct version.

Comment: the project was done in MVC 1.. I dont know what happen I redone it instead, it was no big project so it was ok. thanks for reply

Comment: Yes for some reason when I shifted my MVC2 project which did compile, it needed this dll re-added.

Answer (score 3):

- Go back one second.

Answer (score 3):

I got the exact same problem and it was because i was referencing MVC1 rather than MVC2.  In the properties that have the same build numbers of v2.0.50727

I managed to fix this problem by selecting the System.Web.Mvc and viewing its properties and setting the "Specific Version" to "True"

Answer (score 1):

This problem also occurs when you have both versions of MVC i.e 1.0 and 2.0. On all the places like we.config or at project file you may find that reference is for the mvc 2.0 dll

```
 `<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
    PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>`
```

in config  or

```
 `{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};  
  {349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};  
  {fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}`
```

at your project file.

But your project is accessing the MVC 1.0 dll in References folder.

Go to References and delete `System.Web.Mvc` and add the new reference of `System.Web.Mvc`

Answer (score 1):

Its ambiguous namespace,
just remove `using System.Web.Http`

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out Scott Gu's post [here.](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet-mvc2-upgrade-notes)

See the section named "Manually Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Project"